# How to mock a method of a struct that calls another method of the same struct

Tags: go, testing, mocking

I need a little help with mocking `struct` member functions in Go.

Here is the specific use case:

I have a struct `Foo` with a field which represents some internal state of the struct instance. This struct also has two member functions `Bar()` and `Baz()`. I want to test `Baz()` while mocking out `Bar()`.

Thank you for your help.

```
package awesomeProject

import "fmt"

type Foo struct {
    state string
}

func NewFoo(s string) *Foo {
    return &Foo{s}
}

func (f *Foo) Bar() {
    fmt.Println(f.state)
}

func (f *Foo) Baz() {
    if len(f.state) > 0 {
        f.Bar()
    }
}
```

Comment: When using mocks, you mock *types* (really dependencies), not *methods*.

Comment: This is not possible in Go, you'll have to define a new interface type that does Bar, add a new field to Foo that will hold an instance of that interface and have Baz call Bar on that field.

Comment: @mkopriva, can you provide a quick example, if you have one.

Comment: @IllyaChekrygin https://play.golang.org/p/TzByV29DfNB

Comment: Don't mock. Invest your time in useful tests (this is much easier in Go than you might think).